# How Can I Use qTranslate Language Tags in an AJAX Popup

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, magnific-popup, qtranslate

I just set up Magnific Popup but unfortunately, I do not understand how to get qTranslate's language tags to work within the HTML file I created for the AJAX popup.

Or should I be working on embedding a wordpress page (in which the qTranslate plugin works well) within the popup?

The HTML file below with the language tags included can be seen at http://chinasonoma.com/?page_id=9 when "What is Craft Beer?" is clicked on. "中文" should be invisible while English is selected.

This is my first post, so please let me know if you need any further information.

```
<<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="custom-content" class="white-popup-block" style="max-width:600px; margin: 20px auto;">
    <h3>What is Craft Beer?</h3>
    <style>
    #custom-content img {max-width: 100%;margin-bottom: 10px;}
    </style>
    <p>Craft Beer is a specialty product </p>   

    <p><!--:zh-->中文<!--:--></p>

<img src="http://chinasonoma.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/sampler.jpg"/>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is quite simple.

Two possibilities:

1. Proper use of a filter:

   `<p><?php apply_filters('the_content','<!--:zh-- >中文<!--:-->'); ?> </p>`
2. Use the function qtrans_getLanguage();

   `<p><?php if(qtrans_getLanguage()=="zh") { echo "中文"; } ?></p>`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping Blackbam, I tried adding both codes to my whatisbeer.php page but receive a fatal error, call to undefined function.

Does qTranslate not work in this because it is a page I created outside of wordpress? The .php file is located in the wp-content folder, but it is not one I created with the wordpress editor.

Comment: Ah ok, so WordPress is not loaded when calling this PHP-code? So maybe a solution is to load WordPress before calling these functions. Just put the following code `<?php require( '../my_wordpress_install_root/wp-load.php' ); ?>` on top of your template (of course you have to use the correct path).